# Chicken&Egg situation in printing rows while searching in them

Tags: php, database, search

Let's say I have two SQL tables:

```
QYZ: id, uid<user id, FK*>, somedatacolumn
USERS: id<FK*>, name, surname
```

And `$rows` is simply a list of rows from QYZ when I run `SELECT * FROM qyz`.

The objective is to generate an html table that looks like:

```
ID (of QYZ) | User    | Data
    1       | Aaa Bbb | xyzfghh
    2       | Ccc Ddd | dfash
    3       | Aaa Bbb | sdafdfa
```

The following code allows me to search in `Data`, but not `User`...

Please consider the following code:

```
// index.php?q=Something
// Note: the following could have been done through SQL,
// but let's consider it wasn't (I'm well aware of the consequences).
$search=$_REQUEST['q'];
foreach($rows as $i=>$row){
    $found=false;
    foreach((array)$row as $k=>$v){
        if(stripos($v,$search)!==false){
            $found=true;
            break; // <- optimization
        }
    }
    if(!$found)unset($rows[$i]);
}

// And somewhere later on...
echo '<table>';
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach((array)$row as $k=>$v){
        echo '<td>';
        echo formatter($row,$k,$v); // <- in truth, I'm using call_user_func(),
                               // but for the sake of argument...
        echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

// And maybe somewhere earlier, perhaps passed as a function argument...
function formatter($row,$column,$cell){
    switch($column){
        case 'uid':
            $cell=getUser($cell)->name().' '.getUser($cell)->surname();
    }
    return htmlspecialchars(''.$cell,ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

I know it's a bit jumbled up. Hopefully it's not too difficult to understand. In short, here's what it does:

- we first filter out the database results ($rows) according a search term (search system is very basic, *do not suggest alternative search engines, that's not the point*).
- next we print a table of the search results using a formatting function...
- ...which we might have defined somewhere earlier*
- and which, using caching techniques, we print out mixed db data without any further queries (thus the reason I didn't `SELECT * FROM xyz, users WHERE xyz.uid=users.id`
- **it is important to note that as a side effect, I'm using getUser()**

The problem? I can't search for user "John Doe" since at the time the search is done, only user IDs are known (formatting as done later on) [as well as the fact that user John Doe doesn't exist **=P**].

In this specific case, we could fix it easily with some specific coding (eg: adding getUser to search filter code). But sometimes, the formatting routine is quite complex, much more than just resolving an ID to a name, (such as parsing WikiMarkup or same advanced computations).

The logical solution would be to do the search at the end, ie after rendering the rows.
With output buffering(needed since some stuff in formatter() is written directly) and `strip_tags`, this would be as easy as:

```
ob_start();
foreach($rows as $row){
    foreach((array)$row as $k=>$v){
        echo '<td>'.formatter($row,$k,$v).'</td>';
        stripos(strip_tags(ob_get_contents()),$search)!==false
            ? ob_flush() : ob_clean();
    }
}
ob_end_clean();
```

Basically, we flush the buffer if search query matches, otherwise, we clear the buffer.

Although I believe it ought to work, and might even require less CPU cycles, it sounds like a lot of content manipulation.

Oh, and come to think of it, scratch off output buffering - it makes absolutely no sense if I had to introduce pagination (which I have every intention to do so).

See where the problem lies? It needs to manipulate/search the generated data (search) to actually generate the right one. Sounds awfully inefficient in several counts.

**PS**: This is important. **This system is generic**, which is why I can't make it specific for  certain situation.

Comment: I am having difficulty working out what you are asking?

Comment: @Finbarr - This is mostly a logical issue. I'm afraid you have to read it to the very end. **:)**

Comment: I don't know if I'm reading this wrong, but the second foreach seems to have no closing brace - is the brace not aligned/is this intentional?

Comment: @Christian. I read it through the very end and I don't see a question here other than "The problem?" and "See where the problem lies?" (I don't.) Could you be a bit more specific? I'm not sure whether your problem is in the searching part or the formatting part. Maybe you could give an example.

Comment: The second from top? You were right, it in fact had an additional `{` (since it's just a single if block).

Comment: Okay, thanks. In addition, why can't you simply determine the user id from the name at the start of your search? Would you mind posting your schema?

Comment: @Jason - em: *It needs to manipulate/search the generated data (search) to actually generate the right one. Sounds awfully inefficient in several counts.* That is to say, it needs to create the full table/page the first time and then search through it to actually pick up the right rows (and hence create a new table/page).

Comment: ...and I just scanned it again, and I think this is part of the confusion: your question talks about code *implementation* and those of us reading it are having some trouble figuring out what the *requirements* of the code.

Comment: @Christian From what you said, you need to generate a table to and then search through that, is that not a prime spot for a recursive function?

Comment: @mazzzzz - But the issue is that I kind of do not want to generate one big table (of some 5k results) in order to trim down to some 10 actual ones. It's the same reason why we join SQL statements together to get what we want specifically, but if this stuff is dynamic, and SQL just can't help, it will end up really slow really quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The logical solution would be to do the search at the end, ie after rendering the rows.

Why? Your data access should get all the information needed to choose rows in one round of querying. If you're using a database, you should just be able to join tables together. If you're not using a database, I would question that decision.

As far as formatting/rendering, if the data to be displayed is homogeneous in structure (same for each row), then you should be able to get all that in the initial round of querying. If it's heterogeneous in structure, maybe you'd have to do additional queries later.

I would strongly suggest you decouple data querying and rendering as much as possible, otherwise you have one large and difficult-to-maintain problem instead of two smaller ones.

Comment: With regards to logic/data coding, that's pretty much because of showing it as a test case. You have a great point though, you mention using vs not using a database, and that's the issue. The formatting routine as you can see, joins stuff from elsewhere. This may or may not be a database. And it is this that worries me, PHP is slow at querying - and we all agree linking stuff together and filtering out is one of the main features of SQL.

Comment: Aha, that gives me an idea actually. Instead of just having the formatting routine, the API developer actually supplies two: a search routine and the formatting one. Basically, the search routine would be a toned-down version of the later one, which joins data in one block best fit for search.